# TypeScript is not adding resolved path into Custom Angular library .d.ts file

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Angular library I have just updated to Angular v12, and TypeScript to 4.2.4, and am having compile errors now when trying to use this build library.

I found the problem to be in one of the generated .d.ts files.

Previously, before the update, when it was working, it has the following line

```
readonly headerComponents: QueryList<import("../data-grid-column-header/data-grid-column-header.component").DataGridColumnHeaderComponent>;
```

However, now when I built is, it seem be using one of the paths setup in tsconfi.json compileOptionPaths., ie I have

```
     {
        "include": [
            "src",
            "node_modules/cypress"
        ],
        "exclude": [
            "node_modules/cypress"
        ],
        "compileOnSave": false,
        "compilerOptions": {
            "baseUrl": "./",
            "downlevelIteration": true,
            "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
            "sourceMap": true,
            "declaration": false,
            "module": "es2015",
            "moduleResolution": "node",
            "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
            "experimentalDecorators": true,
            "importHelpers": true,
            "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
            "target": "es5",
            "typeRoots": [
                "node_modules/@types"
            ],    
            "lib": [
                "es2018",
                "dom"
            ],
            "paths": {
                "@angular/*": [
                    "node_modules/@angular/*"
                ],
                "@mycompany/myapp-ui": [
                    "projects/myapp-ui/src/public-api.ts"
                ],
                "@mycompany/myapp-ui/*": [
                    "projects/myapp-ui/src/*"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

And now in the .d.ts file I have

```
 get headerComponents(): QueryList<import("@mycompany/myapp-ui").DataGridColumnHeaderComponent>;
```

And when you hover over ths, the tooltip is `Cannot find module '@mycompany/myapp-ui' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)`

If I replace this with what it use to have (ie the resolved path), then all is good.

Why is it outputting this, and how I can stop it?

### Update 1

One component is imported into another, eg I have

[image]

And in `data-grid-header.component.ts`, I have

```
import { DataGridColumnHeaderComponent } from '../data-grid-column-header/data-grid-column-header.component';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why this happens**

This usually happens if you have a transitive or implicit import of a type through another file.

Scenario:

- `A` exports `DataGridColumnHeaderComponent`
- `B` imports `DataGridColumnHeaderComponent` from `A`

  - `B` exports a function that returns a `DataGridColumnHeaderComponent`
- `C` imports and calls the function from `B`

  - The `DataGridColumnHeaderComponent` type is only known indirectly via `B`'s import
  - So TypeScript outputs the type as `import("A").DataGridColumnHeaderComponent`

**Example:**

```
// @mycompany/myapp-ui/data-grid-column-header.component.ts
// A - exports some type DataGridColumnHeaderComponent

export class DataGridColumnHeaderComponent {
    //...   
}
```

```
// @mycompany/example-library/index.ts
// B - imports `DataGridColumnHeaderComponent` and does something that publicly exposes that type

import { DataGridColumnHeaderComponent } from '@mycompany/myapp-ui';

export function doSomething(): DataGridColumnHeaderComponent {
    return DataGridColumnHeaderComponent;
}
```

```
// my-application/index.ts
// C - uses the library and accesses the `DataGridColumnHeaderComponent` type via B.
// We don't have an explicit import of this type in this file.

import { doSomething } from '@mycompany/example-library';

// `result` has the type `DataGridColumnHeaderComponent`, but the type is only known via B.
const result = doSomething();
```

In this example our application (`C`) has a transitive dependency on `DataGridColumnHeaderComponent`; we only know about that type *through* `B`.

So TypeScript output the type as: `import("@mycompany/myapp-ui").DataGridColumnHeaderComponent`.

---

**How to fix it**

The solution is to explicitly import the same dependency so TypeScript doesn't output a relative path to the type.

```
// C (updated)
import { doSomething } from '@mycompany/example-library';

// !! Explicitly import the type here !!
import { DataGridColumnHeaderComponent } from '@mycompany/myapp-ui';
// or
import type { DataGridColumnHeaderComponent } from '@mycompany/myapp-ui';


const result: DataGridColumnHeaderComponent = doSomething();
```

---

**Alternative fix**

If you can't have/don't want a dependency across those projects, then an alternative would be to re-export the type in the intermediate project/file and import everything from there.

```
// B (updated)
import { DataGridColumnHeaderComponent } from '@mycompany/myapp-ui';

export function doSomething(): DataGridColumnHeaderComponent {
    return DataGridColumnHeaderComponent;
}

// !! Export the type here !!
export {
    DataGridColumnHeaderComponent
};
```

```
// C (updated)
import { doSomething, DataGridColumnHeaderComponent } from '@mycompany/example-library';

const result: DataGridColumnHeaderComponent = doSomething();
```

Comment: Thanks for all that. I added a little information after Update1 (as can't add here in the comments).  I did change the import of one component into the other into as you have above, ie `import { DataGridColumnHeaderComponent } from '@mycompany/my-ui';` but now the build will give me `ERROR: Entry point @micromine/dome-ui has a circular dependency on itself.`

Comment: You will need to adjust the import statement to match your specific situation. In your case it looks like the type is inside the same project so a relative path is appropriate. So one file might have `import { DataGridColumnHeaderComponent } from '../data-grid-column-header/data-grid-column-header.component';` and the other might have something like `import { DataGridColumnHeaderComponent } from './components/some/path/data-grid-column-header/data-grid-column-header.component';`. If the type was in some other external module then you could use `import {...} from '@mycompany/whatever'`.

Comment: Thanks for that! What you originally mentioned was correct (I misunderstood a little). We had an implicit import in the .ts file. We "typed" the getter return type, and selected the relative path as the import, and after that all work fine.